# Print text from {start} to {end} inclusive

Tags: javascript, html, dom

There is a DOM structure like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <p>(1)</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <p>(2)</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>(3)</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <p>(4)</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div id="start">
                                <p>(5)</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p>(6)</p>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p>(7)</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>(8)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>(9)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>(10)</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p>(11)</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <p>(12)</p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="end">
                            <p>(13)</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p>(14)</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>(15)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Three parameters are supplied to the input:

1. Link to root
2. Link to the text node of the element {start}
3. Link to the text node of the element {end}

Task: print text between {start} and {end}, including {start} and {end}

For the example above, this would be: `(5) (6) (7) (8) (9) (10) (11) (12) (13)`

Anything I could think of... **script.js:**

```
const rootNode = document.getElementById('root');
const startNode = document.getElementById('start');
const endNode = document.getElementById('end');

if (startNode == rootNode && rootNode == endNode) {
    console.log(rootNode.innerText);
} else {
    let parentsStart = [startNode.parentNode];
    let parentsEnd = [endNode.parentNode];

    while (parentsStart[0] != rootNode) {
        parentsStart.unshift(parentsStart[0].parentNode);
    }

    while (parentsEnd[0] != rootNode) {
        parentsEnd.unshift(parentsEnd[0].parentNode);
    }

    let visited = [];
    let flag = false;
    let foundText = '';

    compute(rootNode);

    console.log(foundText);

    function compute(node) {
        if (visited.indexOf(node)) {
            visited.push(node);
            if (node == startNode && !flag) {
                flag = true;
            }
            if (node.nodeType == node.ELEMENT_NODE && flag && parentsEnd.indexOf(node) == -1) {
                foundText += node.innerText + ' ';
            }
            if (node == endNode && flag) {
                flag = false;
            }
            if (node.hasChildNodes) {
                for (let item of node.childNodes) {
                    compute(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not a solution...

Comment: "*But this is not a solution*" - why? how does it not work?

Comment: please edit your question header to be in English too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to make use of the [`Range` DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) - this is literally what it was made for:

```
function getTextFrom(start, end) {
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.setStartBefore(start);
    range.setEndAfter(end);
    return range.toString();
}
```

In your example:

```js
const range = document.createRange();
range.setStartBefore(document.getElementById('start'));
range.setEndAfter(document.getElementById('end'));
console.log(range.toString());
```

```html
<div id="root">
    <ul>
        <li> Automotive <strong id="start">business</strong> (some text) </li>
        <li> Administrative staff </li>
        <li> Banks, <strong> investments </strong>, leasing </li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <h3 id="end"> Working in America: </h3>
        <p> Work makes up a large part of life for almost all of us. But nothing lasts forever: it happens that
            one day
            you have to change your place of work and immerse yourself in the search for vacancies - you want to
            find a good
            an alternative to the current position. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```js
console.log(getfragment(document.getElementById('root')));
// and here the solution as presented by Bergi:
console.log(getTextFrom(document.getElementById('start'),document.getElementById('end')));

function getfragment(el){
  let e=document.createElement('div');
  e.innerHTML=el.innerHTML; // clone el;
  let st=e.querySelector("#start"),en=e.querySelector("#end");
  st.innerHTML="#start#"+st.innerHTML;  // make ids #start and #end  
  en.innerHTML=en.innerHTML+"#end#";    // visible ...
  return e.innerText.match(/start#([\w\W\n]*)#end/)[1] // ... and filter text between them
         .replace(/[\n\s]+/g," ");   // optional: remove surplus blanks and line feeds
}

// and here Bergi's solution:
function getTextFrom(start, end) {
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.setStartBefore(start);
    range.setEndAfter(end);
    return range.toString();
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
        <ul>
            <li> Automotive <strong id="start">business</strong> (some text) </li>
            <li> Administrative staff </li>
            <li> Banks, <strong> investments </strong>, leasing </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <h3 id="end"> Working in America: </h3>
            <p> Work makes up a large part of life for almost all of us. But nothing lasts forever: it happens that
                one day
                you have to change your place of work and immerse yourself in the search for vacancies - you want to
                find a good
                an alternative to the current position. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In `getfragment(el)` I start with creating a clone of the captured element `el` and put it into the independently create `<div>` element `e`.

The work starts there: I first make the `id`s "start" and "end" visible by making them appear in the actual `.innerHTML` of their respective elements. Having done that I can filter out the desired text fragment by applying a regular expression on the `innerText` of `e`:

```
e.innerText.match(/start#([\w\W\n]*)#end/)[1]
```

In the regular expression I first tried matching "anything" between the two markers simply with `.*`. This unfortunately failed as it *does not match newlines* (`\n`). For this reason I am now looking for `[\w\W\n]*` which is "any repetition of word-characters, non-word-characters(=blanks, punctuation etc.) and newlines.

Comment: OK, this is *not* the accepted answer. I *fully agree* that @Folco's solution is just that much easier and definitely the right choice! But why does this mean that I deserve a downvote? Is there a SO rule I contravened or did I do something else rude here?

Comment: No, everything is fine! Thank you for your work, I praised him with a positive voice, but since this account was created today, the voice is not displayed, perhaps someone else did not like it ...
But I really liked your decision, and the decision of your colleague, I didn’t know that this is possible, only now I’m starting to learn the DOM, I could choose two solutions, I would do it ...

Comment: Sorry, in the rush I mixed up the names. It was of course @Bergi who came up with the rightfully accepted solution. Will correct my post accordingly!